# Issues with AP and station mode simultaneously on a AP-STA wifi module

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, hostapd, wireshark, access-point

I have an iMX8MP board running Linux. The board is equipped with a Wifi module with AP-STA capability. I want this system to start an access point at boot and to connect to an external wifi once the credentials are provided, without killing the AP. The AP is launched using hostapd:

```
#!/bin/bash
modprobe brcmfmac
iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan1 type __ap
ifconfig wlan1 192.168.3.1 up 
udhcpd /etc/udhcpd.conf
hostapd /etc/myhostapd.conf
```

The connection to the wifi is done using wpa_supplicant (NetworkManager is not available):

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
wpa_supplicant -c /home/root/wpa.conf -i wlan0 -B # in questo momento il cliento
udhcpc -i wlan0 -b
```

Now, when the board connects to the wifi, every client that was previously connected to the AP, stays connected and is still able to ping the board. At the same time, the board can ping both the clients and the internet. However, new clients are not able to connect to the AP. The only way is to restart hostapd.

I tried to use Wireshark to investigate this problem, using a filter on the AP SSID. When the board is running hostapd (but before calling wpa_supplicant), the following packets are periodically captured:

```
No. Time Source Destination Protocol Length Info
32410   709.786863608   LsResear_6b:3f:17   Broadcast   802.11  204 Beacon frame, SN=150, FN=0, Flags=........, BI=100, SSID=MY-AP-SSID

32268   707.492592614   LsResear_6b:3f:17   72:23:3e:ee:74:61   802.11  198 Probe Response, SN=123, FN=0, Flags=....R..., BI=100, SSID=MY-AP-SSID

32098   705.310088818   LsResear_6b:3f:17   IntelCor_b5:58:ec   802.11  198 Probe Response, SN=92, FN=0, Flags=....R..., BI=100, SSID=MY-AP-SSID

32002   704.240712766   LsResear_6b:3f:17   AlpsElec_31:89:ab   802.11  198 Probe Response, SN=73, FN=0, Flags=....R..., BI=100, SSID=MY-AP-SSID
```

When wpa_supplicant is launched, the following packet is captured once, and then **no more packets are captured**.

```
801 15.307033347    Azurewav_1c:29:49   Broadcast   802.11  244 Probe Request, SN=3025, FN=0, Flags=........, SSID=MY-AP-SSID
```

This is the moment when no new clients can connect to the AP, but clients that were already connected have no problems. If I restart the AP, new clients can connect. During the restart, some of the periodic packets reported above are captured for a few seconds, but then they stop. If I also kill wpa_supplicant, periodic packets are back.

How can I fix this problem? Can I connect to the wifi without having to restart the AP?